# com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: unknown error: Element is not clickable

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Environment
Chrome : Version 39.0.2171.95
Chrome Driver : 2.13 (Latest)
Selenium WebDriver

I need to enter key in textbox and then click on enter button. Script is working fine in IE and FF. But when it comes to chrome I find an error

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (221, 191). Other element would receive the click:

Some solutions which I saw is using

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,\"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+\")");

but it dint work out for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **waiting for the element to be clickable** and then clicking on it.

You can use the below code for that:

```
//Wait for 20 seconds to detect that the element is clickable, and then clicking on it
try{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//xpath of the Enter button")));
    element.click();
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error while waiting for the element to be clickable: "+e.getMessage());
}
```